# iframe as a nested element of pre element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use [prism](http://prismjs.com/) to highlight the syntax of an `iframe` which will be inserted with javascript/jquery. The structure looks something like:

`<pre>
    <code id="iframeWrapper" class="language-markup">
        <!-- IFRAME GOES HERE -->
    </code>
</pre>`

inside the `code` element I'd like to inject an iframe - how can I do that? I've tried setting the `innerHtml` of `iframeWrapper` but that hasn't work. I've also tried appending the `iframe` as a `childElement` of `iframeWrapper`, which also didn't work.

Code looks like...

`<pre><code id="iframe" class="language-markup"></code></pre>`

```
function generateIFrame(){
var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
$("#iframe").html('&lt;iframe src=\'http://example.com/?\n'
+ 'guid="+$("#guid").val()+"\n'
+ '&email="+$("#email").val()+"\n'
+ '&btc="+$("#btc").val()+"\n'
+ '&subref="+$("#subref").val()+"\n'
+ '&snip="+$("#snip").val()+"\n'
+ '&callback="+$("#callback").val()+"\n'
+ '&donnee="+$("#donnee").val()+"\n'
+ '\'&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;');
```

}

Comment: Hope you aren't expecting the parents of the iframe to impact how document inside iframe looks

Comment: ...no not at all... I'm preserving the iframe code, not embedding it.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#iframeWrapper').html(yourIframeHtmlCode);
```

Example:

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
  $('#iFrameWrapper').html('<iframe src="http://example.com" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='iFrameWrapper'></div>
<button id='clickMe'>Show iframe</button>
```

Comment: ...that writes the iframe to the dom with quotes round it - and as such is not picked up as markup by prism.

Comment: It does work when used correctly, can we see your code?

Answer (score 0):

Can use `text()` instead of `html()` to set it:

```
$('#iframeWrapper').text('<iframe src="http://example.com" width="800px" height="800px"></iframe>');
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xpm8ebvL/)**</kbd>

Comment: ...prints `&lt` and `&gt` rather than < and > :/

Comment: not in 2 browsers I checked but those are the proper html entities. You never said that was a problem or what expected results were

Comment: ...If I use < and > instead of `&lt` and `&gt` then it just embeds it as if it was an iframe - which I don't want to do. I just want to preserve the iframe code.

Comment: Well the jsfiddle preserves it in both firefox and chrome for me.

Comment: ...If you look at the output in the element inspector, does it have quotes round it?

Comment: does what have quotes? It shows me exactly what I see in the docuemnt

Comment: ...the iframe that you've created... could you send me a link to the jsfiddle?

Comment: it's in the `demo` button